# Accessing POST data from ASCX user control on parent page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0, user-controls, webforms

I have an ASP.NET page (WebForm) on which I set the content of a central DIV by **dynamically** loading one of five user controls during `Page_Load`, dependant on the stage of the application.

One of the user controls contains radio buttons and a text box together with a submit button. What I want to do is process that information when the form is posted using the submit button.

I could do this with an AJAX call using jQuery, but I don't really want to do that, so I'm trying to access the form data on postback, but on page load following the postback the data is not present in the Request.Form object.

Looking at what I need to do it seems pretty simple and I'm sure is once you've got your head around it, but I can't find out how to carry this out. Some of the things I have read refer to event bubbling, but that doesn't make too much sense in this scenario.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to post the page back to itself to capture the values from the form elements via the Request object, store them in the database, and then display a confirmation message (or something else) on postback, and not re-display the same control again. So I won't be loading the same user control again.

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Maybe the post data is not yet ready, when the control's `Page_Load` fires but first when the page's `Page_Load` fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad. I totally forgot that radio buttons and checkboxes don't post back anything if they are not selected. I knew that, but had just forgotten it. Darn that HTML!! Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic controls have to be added on `PreInit` and added back on each postback to show up on the server side.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but I don't want to load the same controls back on postback, I want to take the values from them, stick them in a database, and then the page will display a confirmation message, or another user control confirming the action.

Comment: Data that is posted back is available in the Request object.  You can explicitly fetch the values from the Request object in your parent page, and then you can use them as necessary.

Comment: @Jason: Yeah, I know that is usually the case and what I would expect, but when I initiate the post back from the user control and then try to access the data from the user control form objects in the Request object on the parent page, the posted data is not present. That's my whole problem here.

Comment: so the problem is that the page isn't posting back properly.  i think your best approach is to remove functionality until your pages are behaving as expected.  once you know what's going on, add the desired functionality in discrete chunks.

Comment: Yep already tried that. I've dropped it down to the basics of loading the user control dynamically on `Page_Load` using `myPanel.Controls.Add(<control>)`, then when the submit button on that user control posts posts the form back to the parent page the Request object does not hold the form values that should have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Page.LoadControl to dynamically load your User Controls, you should be able to do something like this.

```
Dim strTextboxTextValue As String = CType(CType(YourPlaceHolder.FindControl("YourUserControlId"), UserControl).FindControl("YourTextBoxID"), TextBox).Text
```

Comment: Yes but I'm not loading the same user control on postback. I just want to access the data posted back to the page and display something else after processing it.